# How can I divide bitsets?

Tags: c++, bitset

I use two [bitsets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) to store two polynomials. I want one of them to be divided by 2nd and I want to get remainder after division. For example if I would like it on the paper:

```
w1= 110011010000000
w2 = 1111001

           101000100
     110011010000000 : 1111001
     1111001
     --1111110
       1111001
       ----1110000
           1111001
           ---100100 = remainder
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have implemented?

Comment: Its not enought to divide by two, i need to divide one polynomial by another polynomial:
std::bitset<30> a("110011010000000");

std::bitset<30> b("1111001");

and i want remainder in std::bitset<30> c;

Comment: Sorry, turned out I misread your question. But you should really take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very few CPUs have builtin instructions for GF(2) division like this, so you'll need to implement it yourself with shifts and xors.  Basically, you implement it exactly like you did it on paper -- shift the divisor up until its top bit matches that of dividend, then xor and shift back down, recording each position where you need an xor as a bit of the quotient.  If all the polynomials in question fit in a single word, you can just use `unsigned` integer types for it.  Otherwise, you'll need some multiprecision bitset type.  The C++ `std::bitset` can be used for this, despite its problems (no easy way to convert between bitsets of different sizes, no bitscan functions).

```
template<size_t N> int top_bit_set(const bitset<N> &a) {
    int i;
    for (i = N-1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (a.test(i)) break;
    return i;
}


template<size_t N>
bitset<N> gf2_div(bitset<N> dividend, bitset<N> divisor, bitset<N> &remainder) {
    bitset<N> quotient(0);
    int divisor_size = top_bit_set(divisor);
    if (divisor_size < 0) throw divide_by_zero();
    int bit;
    while ((bit = top_bit_set(dividend)) >= divisor_size) {
        quotient.set(bit - divisor_size);
        dividend ^= divisor << (bit - divisor_size); }
    remainder = dividend;
    return quotient;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, im begginer and i dont understand your functions. I just need one function that will take two parameters(std::bitset) containing polynomials and will return 3rd bitset with remainder. Here is better example: http://s17.postimg.org/9vb29rw8v/kodo.png
I want to pass two bitsets and get one bitset containing remainder

Comment: `gf2_div` does exactly that, taking the two bitsets as its first 2 args, and writing the remainder to the 3rd arg.  You can ignore the quotient returned if you don't care about it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working now. There was small error that variable i was out of the scope and i recived a lot of compiller warnings and errors. I also didnt use templates very often in the past so this function was a bit scary for me, and i didnt know why i takes 3 parameters. Now everything is clear. Thanks a lot agine. :)